# Connecting to Core Service via .NET in SDL Web 8

Tags: core-service, web8

I'm trying to connect to the Core Service and retrieve a Component to check its existence.

I created a console application to call the client. In my `App.config` file, I added the binding and endpoint information as below. When I added a `basicHttp` binding, the app executed normally but no correct result. It seems that protocol is different from that used in the CMS. So I converted the binding to `wsHttpBinding`. But a NullReference error came out one by one.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="EndPoint" value="CoreService"/>
<add key="Username" value="USERNAME"/>
<add key="Password" value="PASSWORD"/>
</appSettings>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CoreService_wsHttpBinding" transactionFlow="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" />
      <!-- For HTTPS, use mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" -->
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
   </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
<client>
<endpoint name="CoreService"      address="http://localhost/webservices/CoreService201501.svc/wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CoreService_wsHttpBinding" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService">
     <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Could anyone tell me that which config file should I refer to when I config the `App.config` of my application.(`web.config` of `WebRoot` or the `Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll.config` ?)

I'm a tiro in this area.
Any advice would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I use a basicHttpbinding and endpoint to create a client, it worked, but the protocolException happened. When I changed to a wsHttpBinding and endpoint to create a client, it failed.(The client I created is null.)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithConfigFile

Comment: Yes. I copied the binding & endpoint information from coreservice.client.dll.config. When I use basicHttp, it came out a System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException. If changed to wsHttp, it came out a communicationobjectfaultedexception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using following stuff for non-AD account. Its working fine.

following setting in my app.config

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://myend/webservices/CoreService201501.svc/wsHttp"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService"
          name="wsHttp">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
```

---

Following to create instance of CoreService name SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("**wsHttp**"); this name matches with endpoint name in config

```
 public static Client GetClientInstance()
        {

            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("wsHttp");

                var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreServiceUserName"];
                var domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreServiceDomain"];
                var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreServicePassword"];

                NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
                                   _instance.CoreServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;
            }
            return _instance;
        }
```